# How to build a simple smart home app to connect IOT?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I want to create a smart home app Google Home using Actions SDK. As it is now, I have a cloud server and its OAuth 2.0 API and some real IOT devices, all the cloud environment is prepared. When I 've browsed the document of [Smart Home](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app), I feel confused, I edit a json file and upload it to my google project with gaction, and isn't done? If it is, How to handle the response json of SNYC,QUERY and EXECUTE? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is really broad. Please limit it to a specific problem we can solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Actions on Google console](https://console.actions.google.com/) for your project, there should be a webhook field. You put the URL that the HomeGraph will call. In your webhook, you'll receive a JSON payload that contains the `intent` and other parameters for you to handle.

```
let reqdata = request.body;
let input = reqdata.inputs[0];
let intent = input.intent;
switch (intent) {
    case "action.devices.SYNC":
      console.log('post /ha SYNC');
      // Do sync
      break;
    case "action.devices.QUERY":
      console.log('post /ha QUERY');
      // Do query
      break;
    case "action.devices.EXECUTE":
      console.log('post /ha EXECUTE');
      // Do execute
      break;
    default:
      response.status(401).set({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization'
      }).json({error: "missing intent"});
      break;
  }
```

You should return a JSON payload as a response.

The actual way to adjust your IoT device is entirely dependent on your server and device implementation.

You can check out [the sample project](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs) to figure out a bit more.